# Make CSS height goes up instead of down

Tags: css

I got this piece of code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
 background: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    transition: height 0.3s, background 0.5s;
}
div:hover {
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 450px;
    background: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you hover onto onto one of the `<div>`, it's height will be change. Is there any way to make the height goes up instead of down?(The `<div>` begin at the bottom). Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm having trouble what you want. Could you add a diagram? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're looking for this:  https://jsfiddle.net/kylemartin/92m870dx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 `flexbox` is what you're looking for.

Your HTML:

```
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
```

And then your styling:

```
.cont{
   display:flex;
   align-items:flex-end;
   height:500px;
}
.item {
   background: black;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   transition: height 0.3s, background 0.5s;
}
.item:hover {
  height: 450px;
  background: white;
}
```

You can see it in action here:  https://jsfiddle.net/kylemartin/92m870dx/

An awesome reference for `flexbox` can be found here:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

With `flexbox`, you can force elements to sit at the bottom of a parent `<div>` (hence the `flex-end`), which then automatically makes the `<div>`s pop upward on hover.  (`flexbox` is pretty nifty)

Comment: When i do this, there's a whitespace beneath the `<div>`s

Comment: What do you mean by that?  You'll have to adjust the styling of your `.cont` `<div>` to fit in the space you have.  I just used 500px as a demo.